# Python comparing data in Pandas format mismatch

Tags: python, pandas

I have the input below with data (test.csv)

```
date,time
26-02-2024,8:01
26-02-2024,8:01
26-02-2024,7:59
26-02-2024,7:59
26-02-2024,7:56
26-02-2024,7:55
26-02-2024,7:55
26-02-2024,7:53
26-02-2024,7:52
26-02-2024,7:52
```

Now I have the code below

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df[(datetime.strptime(str(df['date']),'%Y-%m-%d') <= datetime.now())]
```

I get the error

> ValueError: time data '0    26-02-2024\n1    26-02-2024\n2
> 26-02-2024\n3    26-02-2024\n4    26-02-2024\n5    26-02-2024\n6
> 26-02-2024\n7    26-02-2024\n8    26-02-2024\n9    26-02-2024\nName:
> date, dtype: object' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

When I try

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I get get the following error:

> ValueError: time data "26-02-2024" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d", at
> position 0. You might want to try:

When I try

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d',errors='coerce')
```

I got null for date column in output, that looks like some error in date column value, but could not figure it out

Unable to find why it is happening

**Update**

Thanks to Panda Kim, changing to date format to %d-%m-%Y it is working , but when I apply same thing on condition it throws error

```
df = df[ pd.to_datetime(start_date,format='%d-%m-%Y') <= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y') <= pd.to_datetime(end_date,format='%d-%m-%Y')]
```

throws error now

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any guidance would be welcome

Comment: `str(df['date'])` is probably a bad idea: it turns the whole columns (Series) into a single string. Which is what you see in the error message.

Comment: There is no need for `str(df['date'])`: `df['date']` should be fine; the entries are already strings. Or the entries are already dates, so do check that option as well..

Comment: @9769953, then it says strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is often the better way to go converting strings to date(time).

Comment: Because datetime.strptime doesn't work vector wise, so it can't use a Series either. Use Pandas functions to convert to datetime, as I've suggested and linked above.

Comment: @9769953, I already tried that, ValueError: time data "26-02-2024" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d", at position 0.

Comment: I have update post with more observations

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I replied to your question, but why haven't you read it? Your code using `to_datetime` has the wrong format, and the correct format is provided in my answer.

Comment: "26-02-2024" is indeed not in the format "%Y-%m-%d". Do double check what you are trying to do, and use the proper format, say "%d-%m-%Y". (You already have a correct answer by Panda Kim anyway, but just to point out your last error).

Answer (score 2):

use following code

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y') <= pd.to_datetime('today')]
```

Comment: When I am trying df = df[ pd.to_datetime(start_Date,format='%d-%m-%Y') <= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y') >= pd.to_datetime(end_date,format='%d-%m-%Y')], it throws ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: start date and end date values are 2024-03-04 00:00:00
and 2024-03-10 00:00:00

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Please use the code provided in the response. The problem lies in your modified code.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it giving the output now, I am implementing that in actual code where i need to check the date in range

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Pandas requires the use of logical bitwise operators(like `&`). Your error is caused by trying to use two comparison operators at once. Additionally, I believe that my role is limited to answering the questions posed, and I am not responsible for providing all the variation codes that you may want to use in your application.

Comment: Yes, I already implemented that, thank you